# What is wrong with this pam_ldap configuration?

Tags: ldap, pam

I've set up LDAP auth for PAM on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I can't log in over SSH even though I know the password is correct. My goal is to have a list of local users, and anyone having an account on the local LDAP server may log in too (these users are (yet) unknown to the Ubuntu machine). I expect the users to be created at first login, including their home folder (but that's not the point of this post).

Main LDAP configuration file:

```
# awk '! /^$/ && ! /^#/' /etc/ldap.conf 
base OU=MyOrg,DC=myit,DC=local
uri ldaps://ad.myit.local:636/
ldap_version 3
binddn ldap@myit.local
bindpw XXXXX
pam_lookup_policy yes
pam_password md5
nss_base_passwd ou=MyOrg,dc=local?sub
nss_base_shadow ou=MyOrg,dc=myit,dc=local?sub
nss_base_group  ou=MyOrg,dc=myit,dc=local?sub
nss_map_objectclass posixAccount user
nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount user
nss_map_attribute uid sAMAccountName
nss_map_attribute homeDirectory unixHomeDirectory
nss_map_attribute shadowLastChange pwdLastSet
nss_map_objectclass posixGroup group
nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member
pam_login_attribute sAMAccountName
pam_filter objectclass=User
pam_password ad
nss_map_attribute userPassword authPassword
ssl on
debug 10
logdir /var/log/ldap
```

I don't know all the settings for the LDAP server (I don't manage it) but I know that the login attribute is `sAMAccountName`, server URI and the bind DN/password are correct (see examples with `ldapsearch` below).

Here are the relevant authentification configuration files:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd: files ldap
group: files ldap
shadow: files ldap
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup: nis
```

and

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

So basically PAM will try unix first, and if the user doesn't exist it will try LDAP before denying.

Here's the proof that the 1st bind credentials are valid:

```
# ldapsearch -H ldaps://ad.myit.local:636 -b 'ou=MyOrg,dc=myit,dc=local' -D ldap@myit.local -W | grep -P 'distinguishedName.*DUFFEZ'
Enter LDAP Password: (XXXX)
distinguishedName: CN=Benoit DUFFEZ,OU=MyOrg,DC=myit,DC=local
```

Then the bind using the DN provided by the lookup done at the first bind:

```
# ldapsearch -H ldaps://ad.myit.local:636 -b 'ou=MyOrg,dc=myit,dc=local' -D "CN=Benoit DUFFEZ,OU=MyOrg,DC=myit,DC=local" -W | grep -P 'distinguishedName.*DUFFEZ'
Enter LDAP Password: (my password)
distinguishedName: CN=Benoit DUFFEZ,OU=MyOrg,DC=myit,DC=local
```

So that works.

Now if I do over SSH, it fails and `auth.log` says:

```
Jun 26 14:28:21 xxx sshd[6925]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.5.177
Jun 26 14:28:21 xxx sshd[6925]: pam_ldap: error trying to bind as user "CN=Benoit DUFFEZ,OU=MyOrg,DC=myit,DC=local" (Invalid credentials)
Jun 26 14:28:23 xxx sshd[6925]: Failed password for invalid user bdu from 192.168.5.177 port 48780 ssh2
```

I've analyzed the logs (see the `debug 10` in `ldap.conf`) and the error is:

```
LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

This is supposedly a valid user but invalid credential.

I don't see what's wrong? The bind DN in `auth.log` is exactly the same as the one I used with my `ldapsearch` command, same password, but it fails.

Comment: Apologies, I was tired and mixed up the lines.

Comment: No worries, that happens! :)